# ExecutorService - Killing thread after some specified time limit

Tags: java, threadpool, runnable, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have created `ExecutorService` and submitted a job. The job might be time-consuming. So I have given `timeout` as 2 seconds. If the execution takes more than 2 seconds, I want to kill that thread.

```
public void threadTest() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        try {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                    System.out.println("process completed after 7 seconds");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        executor.shutdown();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("main start");
        ThreadBreaker tb = new ThreadBreaker();
        tb.threadTest();
        System.out.println("main end");
    }
```

output

```
main start
main end
process completed after 7 seconds
```

The function `threadTest` exited after 2 seconds as I expected. But the submitted job kept running. I want to stop the submitted task if it couldn't complete in a given timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have submitted a task to executorService you've got an Future object. And you can cancel execution by Future.cancel(true) call.

Keep in mind that canceling the active running task is possible when you have accurate InterruptException handling inside a task.

In the example above:

```
 Thread.sleep(7000);
```

will raise an interrupted exception and you should not catch it (or if you catched it re-raise another exception)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ExecutorService` you cannot kill Threads by yourself. ThreadPool decides when to kill a `Thread` (typically it might happen if the `Thread` was interrupted).

In your case you should catch the `TimeoutException` and `cancel` the `Future`. If your "real" task is responsive to interruption(invoking and handling `InterruptedException` correctly) it will work. Otherwise you should check the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` status in a loop.
Your example code will look like :

```
public void threadTest() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> submit = executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            System.out.println("process completed after 7 seconds");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //preserve interruption status. based on this ThreadPool's interruption Policy will decide what to do with the Thread
        }
    });

    try {
        submit.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //handle this
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        submit.cancel(true); //cancel the task
    }
    executor.shutdown();

}
```

Also remember that if you execute a task in a ThreadPool and you execute operations that might from `InterruptedException` in most cases you should preserve the interruption status.